# Unknown reason for malloc "corrupted top size" error

Tags: c, malloc, valgrind, bmp, memory-corruption

I've been working on a small project and while just after finishing a function that indirectly calls the one below, I started getting the `malloc: corrupted top size` error. I have used Valgrind to narrow down the problem to the `fread` in said function, but I cannot find any mistake in how it is written. Am I just blind, or should I start looking elsewhere?

The offending function:

```c
bmpHead_t* readBMPHeader(FILE* inputFile){
    checkBMPFile(inputFile);
    bmpHead_t* newHeader = malloc(sizeof(bmpHead_t));
    int headerSize = sizeof(bmpHead_t) / 2;
    uint16_t* wordBuff = malloc(headerSize);
    fseek(inputFile, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fread(wordBuff, sizeof(uint16_t), headerSize, inputFile);
    newHeader->signature[0] = (uint8_t)((wordBuff[0] & 0xFF00) >> 8);
    newHeader->signature[1] = (uint8_t)(wordBuff[0] & 0xFF);
    uint32_t tmp = ((uint32_t)wordBuff[2] << 16) | wordBuff[1];
    newHeader->fileSize = tmp;
    newHeader->reserved1 = wordBuff[3];
    newHeader->reserved2 = wordBuff[4];
    tmp = ((uint32_t)wordBuff[6] << 16) | wordBuff[5];
    newHeader->offToPixels = tmp;
    return newHeader;
}
```

For context, the header I'm reading is the Windows [BITMAPFILEHEADER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-bitmapfileheader).

Comment: You are fread()-ing `sizeof(uint16_t)*headerSize` bytes into a buffer that is `headerSize` bytes long, so `fread()` is likely writing past the end of the `newHeader`'s buffer and corrupting the heap.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Thank you, that was the solution to my problem. I will update my post accordingly.

Comment: @YourAverageYeet answers should be posted as an Answer (not as updates to the question)

Comment: @M.M Understood, will mark is as such after two days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by Jeremy Friesner in a comment underneath my post, I was allocating an improper amount of memory.